# function of pyqtSlot

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcore

I just read a tutorial about pyqt5 button from [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/pyqt5-buttons/). And the code is as below. There is a question about `button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)` and `@pyqtSlot()`. If I delete `@pyqtSlot()` from the code, it still works. However, the button does not work if I delete `button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)` from the code. So what is the function of `@pyqtSlot()` in this code?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 button - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 320
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        button = QPushButton('PyQt5 button', self)
        button.setToolTip('This is an example button')
        button.move(100,70) 
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        print('PyQt5 button click')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: See [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator)

Answer (score 33):

`button.clicked.connect(self.on_click)` binds signal of a button (`clicked`) to a slot `self.on_click`. Without this binding click will result in no action.

`@pyqtSlot`, in turn, is a decorator which converts simple python method to Qt slot. [Doc](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html#the-pyqtslot-decorator) states:

> Although PyQt5 allows any Python callable to be used as a slot when
>   connecting signals, **it is sometimes necessary** to explicitly mark a
>   Python method as being a Qt slot and to provide a C++ signature for
>   it. PyQt5 provides the pyqtSlot() function decorator to do this.
>
> ...
>
> Connecting a signal to a decorated Python method also has the advantage of **reducing the amount of memory used and is slightly faster**.

When is that decorating *necessary*?

The only case I know is when you want to call methods from a QML interface: you can pass an object derived from `QObject` to QML and call object's methods but only if these methods are decorated with `@pyqtSlot` decorator with defined signature.

For your case consider it as a good practice - denoting a method as a slot for some signal.

Comment: If you use `QMetaObject.invokeMethod` with a QuededConnection, then the method must be known to the Qt Meta Object system. Thus, I believe `@pyqtSlot` is necessary in this case as well. (Although there may be other ways to mark a method for the Qt Meta Object system.)

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1123088/pyqt-signal-slot-connection-performance investigates what "slightly faster" means and comes to the conclusion: use `@pyqtSlot` when generating "large numbers" of QObjects.. for substantial memory savings in such cases.