# Passing check state with QtPushButton.clicked signal

Tags: python, qtpy

I'm working on a project and trying to pass the checked state of a checkable button to a function via  `button.clicked.connect(self.button_checked)` and ran across an issue. If I use the "decoration" `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` before my callable then the checked state will not pass. But if I remove the decoration the function works as expected and written in documentation. See code below for the two cases:

With decoration

```
...
btn = QPushButton("Push")
btn.setCheckable(True)
btn.toggled.connect(self.button_checked)
...
@QtCore.pyqtSlot()
def button_checked(self, checked):
    print("checked", checked)
...
```

I get the error `TypeError: button_checked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checked'` when the button is pushed. But when I remove `QtCore.pyqtSlot()` and just have:

```
...
btn = QPushButton("Push")
btn.setCheckable(True)
btn.toggled.connect(self.button_checked)
...
def button_checked(self, checked):
    print("checked", checked)
...
```

The button works as expected and prints `checked True` or `checked False` depending on the checked state.

What is the `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` for? I am still new to QtPy and don't have a great grasp on this lines purpose. Do I need to explicitly assign a slot in this case? I've found that it can be necessary in some specific situations ([function of pyqtSlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45841843/function-of-pyqtslot)) and is considered good practice, but it seems to have an effect I don't want in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> I get the error TypeError: button_checked() missing 1 required positional argument: 'checked'

That's because your slot doesn't take any arguments.
Change `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` to `@QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)`

> My question is what is the @QtCore.pyqtSlot() for?

It is used by the `QMetaObjectSystem` that is required by C++ Qt to do runtime dynamic stuff, like calling slots with the right signature. [Read more here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/metaobjects.html). In the Python case it is not needed due to the dynamic nature of Python.

Nevertheless it is required if you want to expose your slots away from Python, i.e., to [QML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QML), and it is said to be [slightly faster](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1123088/pyqt-signal-slot-connection-performance).

Comment: This all makes perfect sense now. I was way in over my head when I asked this but I've been learning a lot about Qt, and pyqt specifically. Thanks for the reply